# Specify table to be use for native id generator

Tags: java, hibernate

we are using native id generator of hibernate and in-turn for one of the database hibernate selects to use TableHiLoGenerator.

```
<id name="id" column="ID_">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Is there any way, where we can use other than default table i.e. "hibernate_unique_key"? How to configure table name when one is using native generator?

We have to use native as for Oracle we have to use sequences and for MySQL we have to use identity generator.

Comment: Your question is really confusing.

Comment: In simple terms, we cannot use any other generator than native and if native selects to use TableHiLoGenerator then we have to configure tablename.

Comment: which Database has hilo algorithm as its native sequence generator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just tested this code with MySQL as Database and it works fine:

```
<hibernate-mapping>    
  <class name="hibernate.Student" table="STUDENT">
            <id name="studentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="STUDENT_ID" />
                <generator class="native">
                    <param name="table">HI_VALUE</param>
                    <param name="column">NEXT_VALUE</param>
                    <param name="max_lo">100</param>
                </generator>
            </id>
        .....
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now , when I save my Student class data, then the operation is successful and hibernate does not generate any table *HI_VALUE* in this case. It may generate this table to be used as Id generator when the native Id generation algorithm supported by any Database is HiLO.

However, concrete evidence is something which i dont have to support this.

**UPDATE : It also works just fine with Oracle 11g also.**